# Problem with PDO and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this MYSQL query

```
INSERT INTO log-error VALUES (INT, VARCHAR, VARCHAR, INT, VARCHAR, INT, INT)
```

**SOLUTION**

The special char (-) can be used in mysql table name but have to be surrounded by (`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special char (-) can be used in mysql table name but have to be surrounded by (`).